# Date Filter Not Works on First Day of Month

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
I have one dropdown and two textbox on my page. Now i have to bind the value 
based on dropdown value.

My question is when i am select This Week from dropdown that time it will
display wrong date when first date of month on second textbox.
```

Look at the below example. It is working fine on other date of month but when 
   select `'07/01/2017'` then it's display like this `'01/06/2017'` rather then 
   `'01/07/2017'` on second textbox when we select **This Week**.

```js
$(document).on("change","#selectDates",function() {
            var dropValue = document.getElementById('selectDates').value;
            //All
            if (dropValue == "1") {
                $('#txtDateFrom').val('');
                $('#txtDateTo').val('');
            }
                //Today
            else if (dropValue == "2") {
                var back_GTM = new Date();
                $('#txtDateFrom').val(Back_date(back_GTM));
                $('#txtDateTo').val(Back_date(back_GTM));
                
            }
                //This Week
            else if (dropValue == "3") {
                //var curr = new Date; // get current date
                var curr = new Date('07/01/2017'); // get current date
                var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
                var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

                var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
                var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last));

                $('#txtDateFrom').val(Back_date(firstday));
                $('#txtDateTo').val(Back_date(lastday));
                
            }
            });
            
            function Back_date(back_GTM) {
            var b_dd = back_GTM.getDate();
            var b_mm = back_GTM.getMonth() + 1;
            var b_yyyy = back_GTM.getFullYear();
            if (b_dd < 10) {
                b_dd = '0' + b_dd
            }
            if (b_mm < 10) {
                b_mm = '0' + b_mm
            }
            return back_date = b_dd + '/' + b_mm + '/' + b_yyyy;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-style">
                <select id="selectDates">
                    <option value="1" selected>All</option>
                    <option value="2">Today</option>
                    <option value="3">This Week</option>
                     </select>
            </div>
            <br />            <br />

            <div class="input-group input-large" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                <span class="input-group-addon">From</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="form-control dpd1" name="from">
                <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="form-control dpd2" name="to">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two date objects for the cases where a week overlaps 2 months.

Because when you set the date to `-5`, from july 1st, 2017, it correctly calculates the date to sunday june 25th.
But now, the month has changed!

When you set the date to the last day of the week, which is `1`, the month stays to june in the date object.

So having two different date objects to manipulate the dates separately is the fix.

```js
$(document).on("change","#selectDates",function() {
  var dropValue = document.getElementById('selectDates').value;
  //All
  if (dropValue == "1") {
    $('#txtDateFrom').val('');
    $('#txtDateTo').val('');
  }
  //Today
  else if (dropValue == "2") {
    var back_GTM = new Date();
    $('#txtDateFrom').val(Back_date(back_GTM));
    $('#txtDateTo').val(Back_date(back_GTM));

  }
  //This Week
  else if (dropValue == "3") {
    //var curr = new Date; // get current date
    var curr = new Date('07/01/2017'); // get current date
    var curr2 = new Date('07/01/2017'); // get current date - Second date object.
    
    var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
    var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

    var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
    var lastday = new Date(curr2.setDate(last));

    $('#txtDateFrom').val(Back_date(firstday));
    $('#txtDateTo').val(Back_date(lastday));

  }
});

function Back_date(back_GTM) {
  var b_dd = back_GTM.getDate();
  var b_mm = back_GTM.getMonth() + 1;
  var b_yyyy = back_GTM.getFullYear();
  if (b_dd < 10) {
    b_dd = '0' + b_dd
  }
  if (b_mm < 10) {
    b_mm = '0' + b_mm
  }
  return back_date = b_dd + '/' + b_mm + '/' + b_yyyy;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="select-style">
  <select id="selectDates">
    <option value="1" selected>All</option>
    <option value="2">Today</option>
    <option value="3">This Week</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br />            <br />

<div class="input-group input-large" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
  <span class="input-group-addon">From</span>
  <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="form-control dpd1" name="from">
  <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
  <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="form-control dpd2" name="to">
</div>
```

Comment: I rolled back to my first idea...To use two date objects. Because setting the last day before the first doesn't fix the same issue near the end of the month. If you set "06/28/2017"... Result is from 25/07/2017 to 01/07/2017, which is wrong.

Comment: I "rolled-back" to my first edit... And having two date objects is a sure fix.

Comment: I have try with your idea but output break on other date.So can you please update your answer ?. because you haven't use curr2 object.

Comment: Ohh my mistake bro...i can't see curr2 on lastday.

Comment: I have try to add below condition in code and it's also working.no need to get curr2.

if(curr.getDate()>1)
              {
                var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
                var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
              }
              else
              {
                var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last));
                var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
              }

Comment: `if(first>0) {`... I would say. You can try. But I'm sure the use of two objects is safe.

Answer (score 0):

For creating new date you should pass year, month index and date of month as prameters.
Example as follows:

```
var curr = new Date(2017,6,1);
```

Following needs to be fixed in your code:

```
// Needs to fix this
var curr = new Date('07/01/2017');
```

Comment: Thanks for replay..!